# Boost libraries included with mingw

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

Using most recent versions of `mingw-64,` `codeblocks` on win10. 
Simple question. Hoping for a simple answer. mingw-64 includes the boost library. Do the libraries still need to be built or are they ready to go as is from mingW and I can just set the linker to them?

Comment: Check the documentation for mingw-64. That should tell you what you've got and what you need to do to get started. Also see [the documentation for Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) since most of Boost exists outside libraries. (Also: try it. The compiler will complain if it needs libraries that have not been built.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking [support for offsite resources](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Comment: It’s all vague, it’s included but you may need it, maybe you don’t. Some are included, some aren’t. Codeblocks and mingw doesn’t really say. Tried compiling and it complains about missing parts but the libraries I’m looking at are supposed to all be in the header. Was hoping someone just had a yes or no, so I knew where to focus. Thanks for the help. Hope it’s left open a while longer if someone has a yes/no.

Comment: A question about the compiler messages -- instead of about mingw's installation package -- *might* be on-topic. But first try copying the main error message into SO's search field, as the answer might already be out there.